# Wrapping query in IF EXISTS makes it very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, exists, query-performance

I have the below query :

```
select databasename 
from somedb.dbo.bigtable l where databasename ='someval' and source  <>'kt'
and not exists(select 1 from dbo.smalltable c where c.source=l.source)
```

The above query completes in three seconds.

If the above query returns any value, we want the stored procedure to EXIT,so I rewrote it like below:

```
If Exists(
select databasename 
from somedb.dbo.bigtable l where databasename ='someval' and source  <>'kt'
and not exists(select 1 from dbo.smalltable c where c.source=l.source)
)
Begin
Raiserror('Source missing',16,1)
Return
End
```

However this is taking 10 minutes.

I can rewrite the above query like below, which also completes in less than 3 seconds:

```
  select databasename 
from somedb.dbo.bigtable l where databasename ='someval' and source  <>'kt'
and not exists(select 1 from dbo.smalltable c where c.source=l.source
if @@rowcount >0
Begin
Raiserror('Source missing',16,1)
Return
End
```

The issue with above rewrite is that the above query is part of bigger stored procedure and it returns multiple result sets. In C#,we iterate through each result set and do some processing.

The above returns an empty result set, so if I go with this approach, I have to change my C# and do deployment again.

So my question is,

> why does using just `IF EXISTS` changes the plan to take so much time?

Below are the details which may help you and let me know if you need any details:

1. Create table and statistics script to get same plan as mine
2. Slow Execution plan
3. Fast Execution plan

   [Slow plan using Brentozar Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJJpG8V7x) 
   [Fast Plan using Brentozar Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByAeQLN7x)

**Note:** Both queries are the same (using parameters), the only difference is `EXISTS` (I might have made some mistakes while anonymizing though).

The table creation scripts are below:

http://pastebin.com/CgSHeqXc  -- small table stats
http://pastebin.com/GUu9KfpS  -- big table stats

Comment: Discussion on this question has been [moved to this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49721/discussion-between-tom-v-and-thegameiswar).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As has been explained by [Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white) in his blog post: [Inside the Optimizer: Row Goals In Depth](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/18/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.aspx) the `EXISTS` introduces a row goal, which prefers `NESTED LOOPS` or `MERGE JOIN` over `HASH MATCH`

> As a final example, consider that a logical semi-join (such as a
>   sub-query introduced with EXISTS) shares the overall theme: it should
>   be optimised to find the first matching row quickly.

In your query this apparently happens to introduce nested loops and remove parallelism, resulting in a slower plan.

So you would probably need to find a way to rewrite your query without using the `NOT EXISTS` from your query.

You might get away with rewriting your query using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and checking there wasn't a row in smalltable by testing for `NULL`

```
If EXISTS(
    SELECT databasename
    FROM somedb.dbo.bigtable l
    LEFT JOIN dbo.smalltable c ON c.source = l.source
    WHERE databasename = 'someval'
    AND source <> 'kt'
    AND c.source IS NULL
)
```

You could probably use a `EXCEPT` query too, depending on how many fields you need to compare on like this:

```
If EXISTS(
   SELECT source
   FROM somedb.dbo.bigtable l
   WHERE databasename = 'someval'
   AND source <> 'kt'

   EXCEPT

   SELECT source
   FROM dbo.smalltable
)
```

Mind you, [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) has a blog post [providing reasons why he prefers NOT EXISTS](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) which you should read through to see if other approaches work better, and to be aware of the potential correctness issues in case of NULL values.

Related Q & A: [IF EXISTS taking longer than embedded select statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/126235)

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same issue, I did manage to work myself round by avoiding using "EXISTS" and by making use of "COUNT()" function and the "IF...ELSE" statement.

For your example try the following:

```
IF
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(l.databasename) + 1 AS databasename
    FROM somedb.dbo.bigtable AS l

    WHERE   l.databasename ='someval'
        AND l.[source]  <> 'kt'
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.smalltable AS c WHERE c.[source]=l.[source])
) > 1 --Acts like EXISTS
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Source missing', 16, 1)
RETURN
END
```

The reason I'm adding "+ 1" to the count is so that I can use "> 1" in the IF condition, using "> 0" or "<> 0" will trigger the query to use nested loops instead of HASH Match.
Haven't looked into why that's exactly happening would be interesting to find out why.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your query using explicit joins and specify which join operation you want to use (loop, hash or merge) like this.

```
If not exists(
    select databasename 
    from somedb.dbo.bigtable l
    inner hash join dbo.smalltable c 
        on c.source = l.source
where databasename ='someval' and source  <>'kt')
begin
    Raiserror('Source missing',16,1)
    Return
end
```

When using EXISTS or NOT EXISTS the SQL Server generated query plan with NESTED LOOP operation assuming that it should go over all rows in the set one by one looking for the first row to satisfy the condition. Using HASH JOIN will speed it up.

Comment: Than you ,will test it