# Why does adding a TOP 1 dramatically worsen performance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a fairly simple query

```
SELECT TOP 1 dc.DOCUMENT_ID,
        dc.COPIES,
        dc.REQUESTOR,
        dc.D_ID,
        cj.FILE_NUMBER
FROM DOCUMENT_QUEUE dc
JOIN CORRESPONDENCE_JOURNAL cj
    ON dc.DOCUMENT_ID = cj.DOCUMENT_ID
WHERE dc.QUEUE_DATE <= GETDATE()
  AND dc.PRINT_LOCATION = 2
ORDER BY cj.FILE_NUMBER
```

That is giving me horrible performance (like never bothered to wait for it to finish).  The query plan looks like this:

[image]

However if I remove the `TOP 1` I get a plan that looks like this and it runs in 1-2 seconds:

[image]

Correct PK & indexing below.

The fact that the `TOP 1` changed the query plan doesn't surprise me, I'm just a bit surprised that it makes it so much worse.

Note: I've read the results from this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24832/how-and-why-does-top-impact-an-execution-plan) and understand the concept of a `Row Goal` etc.  What I'm curious about is how I can go about changing the query so that it uses the better plan.  Currently I'm dumping the data into a temp table then pulling the first row off of it.  I'm wondering if there is a better method.

**Edit** For people reading this after the fact here are a few extra pieces of information.

- Document_Queue - PK/CI is D_ID and it has ~5k rows.
- Correspondence_Journal - PK/CI is FILE_NUMBER, CORRESPONDENCE_ID and it has ~1.4 mil rows.

When I started there were no other indexes.  I ended up with one on Correspondence_Journal (Document_Id, File_Number)

Comment: Do you have a foreign key constraint that enforces the `DOCUMENT_ID` relationship between the two tables (or does every record in `CORRESPONDENCE_JOURNAL` have a matching record in `DOCUMENT_QUEUE`)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try forcing a [hash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx) join*

```
SELECT TOP 1 
       dc.DOCUMENT_ID,
       dc.COPIES,
       dc.REQUESTOR,
       dc.D_ID,
       cj.FILE_NUMBER
FROM DOCUMENT_QUEUE dc
INNER HASH JOIN CORRESPONDENCE_JOURNAL cj
        ON dc.DOCUMENT_ID = cj.DOCUMENT_ID
       AND dc.QUEUE_DATE <= GETDATE()
       AND dc.PRINT_LOCATION = 2
ORDER BY cj.FILE_NUMBER
```

The optimizer probably thought a loop was going to be better with top 1 and that kind of makes sense but in reality it did not work here.  Just a guess here but maybe the estimated cost of that spool was off - it uses TEMPDB - you may have a poorly performing TEMPDB.

---

* Be careful with [join hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx), because they force plan table access order to match the *written* order of the tables in the query (just as if `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` had been specified). From the documentation link:

[image: BOL extract]

This may not produce any undesirable effects in the example, but in general, it very well might. `FORCE ORDER` (implied or explicit) is a *very* powerful hint that goes beyond enforcing order; it prevents a broad range of optimizer techniques being applied, including partial aggregations and reordering.

An `OPTION (HASH JOIN)` *query* hint may be less intrusive in suitable cases, since this does not imply `FORCE ORDER`. It does, however, apply to all joins in the query. Other solutions are available.

Comment: Looks like the correct answer and the only difference between it and the simpler plan was an additional Sort at the front.

Comment: Not sure I like this answer. Join hints are very invasive. Some simple indexing changes should be tried first, for example index on the date column.

Comment: @usr It is a simple PK join that runs in less one second.  Pretty safe bet here.

Comment: In forcing a hash join, you're forcing a scan of the large table. There are better options.

Answer (score 30):

Since you get the correct plan with the `ORDER BY`, maybe you could just roll your own `TOP` operator?

```
SELECT DOCUMENT_ID, COPIES, REQUESTOR, D_ID, FILE_NUMBER
FROM (
    SELECT dc.DOCUMENT_ID,
           dc.COPIES,
           dc.REQUESTOR,
           dc.D_ID,
           cj.FILE_NUMBER,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cj.FILE_NUMBER) AS _rownum
    FROM DOCUMENT_QUEUE dc
    INNER JOIN CORRESPONDENCE_JOURNAL cj
        ON dc.DOCUMENT_ID = cj.DOCUMENT_ID
    WHERE dc.QUEUE_DATE <= GETDATE()
      AND dc.PRINT_LOCATION = 2
) AS sub
WHERE _rownum=1;
```

In my mind, the query plan for the `ROW_NUMBER()` above should be the same as if you had an `ORDER BY`. The query plan should now have a Segment, Sequence Project and finally a Filter operator, the rest should look just like your good plan.

Comment: Actually while it did give the top operator (and a bunch of other stuff (a sequence project, segment, and sort) ) it still ran subsecond.  I'm going to give the correct answer to @frisbee though since his was first and it's simpler.  Great answer though.

Comment: @KennethFisher, frisbee's answer is simpler, but in the way a sledgehammer drives a finish nail more simply than a standard framing hammer.  It also comes with a lot of risk, especially if left in place for the long haul.  I wouldn't use hints like that except in testing or maybe, MAYBE a fringe exception.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli In this particular case there is only the one join so a number of the concerns go away.  I'm aware of the risks of using a join hint (or query hint) I just think it's justified in this case.

Comment: @KennethFisher Imo, the *main* risk of query hints is that as your data grows or changes, the query plan you enforce can become worse than what the system would have found on its own. You have already seen how a small mistake in the plan can seriously impact performance. Using a hint in production is declaring, "I know this plan will always, *always* be the best because I so fully understand the planner and how my data will behave over the lifetime of this query in production." I have never been that confident about a query.

Answer (score 29):

*Edit: +1 works in this situation because it turns out that `FILE_NUMBER` is a zero-padded string version of an integer. A better solution here for strings is to append `''` (the empty string), as appending a value can affect order, or for numbers to add something which is a constant but contains a non-deterministic function, such as `sign(rand()+1)`. The idea of 'breaking the sort' is still valid here, it's just that my method wasn't ideal.*

+1

No, I don't mean I'm agreeing with anything, I mean that as a solution. If you change your query to `ORDER BY cj.FILE_NUMBER + 1` then the `TOP 1` will behave differently.

You see, with the small row goal in place for an ordered query, the system will try to consume the data in order, to avoid having a Sort operator. It will also avoid building a hash table, figuring that it probably doesn't have to do too much work to find that first row. In your case, this is wrong - from the thickness of those arrows, it looks like it's having to consume a lot of data to find a single match.

The thickness of those arrows suggests that your `DOCUMENT_QUEUE` (DQ) table is much smaller than your `CORRESPONDENCE_JOURNAL` (CJ) table. And that the best plan would actually be to check through the DQ rows until a CJ row is found. Indeed, that's what the Query Optimizer (QO) would do if it didn't have this pesky `ORDER BY` in there, that's nicely supported by a covering index on CJ.

So if you dropped the `ORDER BY` completely, I expect you'd get a plan which involved a Nested Loop, iterating over the rows in DQ, seeking into CJ to make sure the row exists. And with `TOP 1`, this would stop after a single row had been pulled.

But if you do actually need the first row in `FILE_NUMBER` order, then you could trick the system into ignoring that index which seems (incorrectly) to be so helpful, by doing `ORDER BY CJ.FILE_NUMBER+1` - which we know will keep the same order as before, but importantly the QO doesn't. The QO will focus on getting the whole set out, so that a Top N Sort operator can be satisfied. This method should produce a plan which contains a Compute Scalar operator to work out the value for ordering, and a Top N Sort operator to get the first row. But to the right of these, you should see a nice Nested Loop, doing lots of Seeks on CJ. And better performance than running through a large table of rows which don't match anything in DQ.

The Hash Match isn't necessarily awful, but if the set of rows you're returning from DQ is way smaller than CJ (as I would expect it to be), then the Hash Match is going to be scanning a lot more of CJ than it needs.

Note: I used +1 instead of +0 because the query optimizer is likely to recognise that +0 changes nothing. Of course, the same thing might apply to the +1, if not now, then at some point in the future.

Answer (score 7):

> I've read the results from this post and understand the concept of a
>   Row Goal etc. What I'm curious about is how I can go about changing
>   the query so that it uses the better plan

Adding [`OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 4138)`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2667211) turns off the effect of row goals for that query only, without being overly prescriptive about the final plan, and will probably be the simplest/most direct way.

If adding this hint gives you a permissions error (required for `DBCC TRACEON`), you could apply it using a plan guide:

[Using `QUERYTRACEON` in plan guides](http://spaghettidba.com/2013/02/08/using-querytraceon-in-plan-guides/) by [spaghettidba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3020/spaghettidba)

...or just use a stored procedure:

[What Permissions does `QUERYTRACEON` Need?](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/what-permissions-does-querytraceon-need/) by [Kendra Little](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/471/kendra)

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of SQL Server offer different (and arguably better) options for dealing with queries that get suboptimal performance when the optimizer is able to apply row goal optimizations. SQL Server 2016 SP1 introduced the `DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL` use hint which has the same effect as trace flag 4138. (See [this blog post](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/02/07/sql-server-row-goal-and-performance/) for an example of how to use it.)

If you're not on that version you can also consider using the `OPTIMIZE FOR` query hint to get a query plan designed to return all rows instead of just 1. The query below will return the same results as the one in the question but it won't be created with the goal of getting just 1 row.

```
DECLARE @top INT = 1;

SELECT TOP (@top) dc.DOCUMENT_ID,
        dc.COPIES,
        dc.REQUESTOR,
        dc.D_ID,
        cj.FILE_NUMBER
FROM DOCUMENT_QUEUE dc
JOIN CORRESPONDENCE_JOURNAL cj
    ON dc.DOCUMENT_ID = cj.DOCUMENT_ID
WHERE dc.QUEUE_DATE <= GETDATE()
  AND dc.PRINT_LOCATION = 2
ORDER BY cj.FILE_NUMBER
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@top = 987654321));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing a `TOP(1)`, I recommend making the `ORDER BY` deterministic for a start. At the very least this will ensure results are functionally predictable (always useful for regression testing). It looks like you need to add `DC.D_ID` and `CJ.CORRESPONDENCE_ID` for that.

When looking at query plans, I sometimes find it instructive to simplify the query:  Possibly select all the relevant dc rows into a temp table in advance, to eliminate issues with cardinality estimation on `QUEUE_DATE` and `PRINT_LOCATION`. This should be fast given the low rowcount.  You can then add indexes to this temp table if necessary without altering the permanent table.