# Slow query - big difference between estimated and actual rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, optimization, cardinality-estimates

At my work, we have a problem with a search query.

If I don't include the lookup into `Table_39` (see below query), it takes 0 seconds to execute the query.
If I include the lookup (`..AND (Not Exists(Select 1 From Table_39 ll ..`), it takes 4 minutes and 57 seconds.

From the execution plan I can see that there is a huge discrepancy between number of expected rows and actual rows, especially in the index for `Table_39` (62.6 estimated vs. 10,956,165), so I tried running `UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN`, but it didn't make any difference.

I would appreciate any input I can get on how to improve the performance of the query that includes the lookup!

Query:

```
select [Table_2].Gid
  into #Table_1
  from [Table_2]
where [Table_2].Gid_Line in ('{31445a8f-900b-4d64-b72f-4e2ac10fd6a7}')
union
select '{31445a8f-900b-4d64-b72f-4e2ac10fd6a7}' as Gid

create unique nonclustered index temp_Table1 on #Table_1 (Gid)
go

select top 500 Table_9.Id
 , Table_9.Gid
 , Table_9.name
 , Table_9.TimeEnter
 , Table_9.Prio
 , Table_9.Direction
 , Table_9.status
 , Table_9.CreaterId
 , Table_9.Subject
 , Table_9.BodyType
 , Table_9.Attach
 , Table_9.FromAddr
 , Table_9.ToAddr
 , Table_9.Gid_LineSet
 , Table_9.xml
from Table_9
where Table_9.Gid_LineSet in (
    select Gid
      from #Table_1
      ) 
  and not exists (
   select 1
   from Table_39 ll
   where ll.Id_Obj_To      = Table_9.Id 
    and ll.Id_ObjType_To   = 5 
    and ll.Id_ObjType_From = 3 
    and ll.Id_Obj_From in (
        9602, 10661, 10857, 10858, 10859, 68823
      , 68824, 68825, 68826, 68827, 68828, 68829
      , 68830, 68831, 68832, 68833, 68834, 372513
      )
    )
order by Table_9.Id desc

drop table #Table_1
```

Execution plan for slow query (with lookup): https://www.dropbox.com/s/rc1i6vvdwwc5hzh/long%20query_Cleaned.sqlplan?dl=0

Execution plan for fast query (no lookup):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjafn5tiy3uepul/short%20query_Cleaned.sqlplan?dl=0

Comment: try this instead of dropbox for sharing execution plans: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting "The supplied XML is not a valid SQL Server query plan xml.". Probably because I used a tool for anonymizing the plans (https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/execution-plan-sanitizer-v2/)

Comment: Please add the DDL including indexes. Do you have statistics on Id_ObjType_To,Id_ObjType_Fromm,Id_Obj_From?

Comment: If your plans don't work on pastetheplan, add them on pastebin or something

Answer (score 4):

#### Row goal

The issue with the estimates is most likely due to the row goal introduced by the `TOP (500)`. See:

[How (and why) does TOP impact an execution plan?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/24832/1192)

If you find the estimates are much better without the `TOP`, or by adding `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 4138)` to the query, that would confirm the hypothesis.

Trace flag 4138 is documented in KB 2667211:

[A query may take a long time to run if the query optimizer uses the Top operator in SQL Server 2008 R2 or in SQL Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2667211).

You should also enable optimizer fixes with trace flag 4199.

#### Indexing

Consider creating an index on table 39, keyed on:

```
Id_Obj_To, Id_ObjType_To, Id_ObjType_From, Id_Obj_From
```

Ensure `Id_Obj_From` has a suitable data type (not e.g. a `max` type).

#### Predicte ordering

The optimizer does not reorder `NOT EXISTS` clauses well in your version of SQL Server. If you expect the `NOT EXISTS` clause to be more selective than the `Gid_LineSet` predicate, reorder those two clauses in the `WHERE` part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the execution plans, the links don't work.

When you do a where not in Table_39, it will return all rows.  Try to put the data from Table_39 into a temp table based on 
"And ll.Id_Obj_From in(9602,10661,10857,10858,10859,68823,68824,68825,68826,68827,68828,68829,68830,68831,68832,68833,68834,372513)"

It will be a smaller table and could reside in memory instead of written to the tempdb.  Only get the columns you need and put them into the temp table.

As an example, I can put 1000 rows into a temp table if they are INT and will reside in memory.  But if I put 2 rows of XML at 20 Meg for each row into a temporary table it will be written to the tempdb.  This is an exagerated sample, but the point is whether a temp table reside in memory or is written to the tempdb depends on the size of the data.