# Performance issues that seem to be server dependent

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2019

I'm dealing with a performance issue that seems to be server dependent. The server in question is version 15.0.4316.3 (X64). Here's the code below.

```sql
SELECT b1.ID
    ,ParentID = (
        SELECT TOP 1 b2.ID
        FROM stgBOMv3 b2
        WHERE b2.id <= b1.id
            AND b2.BOMLevel <= 0
        ORDER BY ID DESC
        )
FROM stgBOMv3 b1
WHERE b1.BOMLevel = 1
```

The query runs fine on my laptop on the exact same dataset, version 15.0.2000.5 (X64). Specifically, it takes about 1 minute to run on my laptop and almost 15 hours on the server. The table has over 6 million rows and appropriate indexes on `ID` and `BOMLevel`.

Are there any obvious things that I'm missing that could be causing my query to take 900 times longer on this server?

---

Edited to add some extra details as requested. As to the purpose of this query, this query has been fit for purpose for years. It's only after migrating to a new server that the query performance tanked.

Table creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.stgBOMv3 (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,ParentID INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES stgBOMv3(id)
    ,TopID INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES stgBOMv3(id)
    ,BOMLevel INT NULL
    ,ItemNumber NVARCHAR(255) NULL --and other columns not included
    )
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_stgBOMv3_BOMLevel]
ON [dbo].[stgBOMv3] ([BOMLevel])
GO
```

Execution plans:

- [Laptop, full dataset, actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ_YbaI53)
- [Server, full dataset, estimated execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJ1G4pIqh)
- [Laptop, top 10, actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1TUf6Ic3)
- [Server, top 10, actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJn-QTI93)

Full dataset actual execution plan for the server is not included, as I'd rather not spend 15 hours generating it

Comment: We would need to see the execution plan of the query from SSMS in order to determine if that query is optimized and if the indexing is appropriate.

Comment: Can you provide the `CREATE TABLE` for `stgBOMv3` - including indexes? And both execution plans

Comment: My spidey senses feel that your query has potential to be logically incorrect too. Are you trying to build a BOM list? This would probably be better handled with window functions or a recursive CTE, both for logical correctness and performance. But as rvsc48 mentioned, we can't really advise on performance issues without the execution plan. You can upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and a link to it in your Post.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've added the extra details you've requested.

Comment: So the decision to do a scan on the inside of the nested loops rather than a seek looks "interesting" - probably a row goal issue. Would you consider a more radical query rewrite? I'd be minded to use window functions here too

Comment: I'm certainly not opposed to a radical rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad plan is doing a backward ordered scan on the inside of the nested loops and will just evaluate the `b2.id < b1.id AND b2.BOMLevel <= 0` predicate against every row until it finds the first one matching the predicate.

[image]

This plan is catastrophically bad for small `b1.id` as it needs to scan the whole table before finding the first row matching the predicate.

I assume that it is undercosting the scan because of the `TOP 1`. See [How (and why) does TOP impact an execution plan?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/24832/3690)

The good plan does seek the `b2.id < b1.id` part and then does a backward direction scan **from that point in the index** until it finds the first row matching the `b2.BOMLevel <= 0` predicate.

The seek looks objectively better in this case so you could try just forcing that. I also changed the `<=` to `<` because we know `ID` is unique and that a row can't meet both of `BOMLevel <= 0` and `BOMLevel = 1`.

```
SELECT b1.ID
    ,ParentID = (
        SELECT TOP 1 b2.ID
        FROM stgBOMv3 b2 WITH (FORCESEEK)
        WHERE b2.id < b1.id
            AND b2.BOMLevel <= 0
        ORDER BY ID DESC
        )
FROM stgBOMv3 b1
WHERE b1.BOMLevel = 1
```

But it looks like the query is returning all rows where `BOMLevel = 1` and the `ID` value from the latest preceding row where `BOMLevel <= 0` aliased as `ParentID`.

TBH this does seem quite confusing as you do have a separate column in the table also called `ParentID` but you state that it has been "fit for purpose for years".

So I'd be hopeful that the below out performs the current "good" plan

```
WITH b1 AS
(
SELECT ID, 
       BOMLevel,
       ParentID  = MAX(CASE WHEN BOMLevel <= 0 THEN ID END) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM stgBOMv3
)
SELECT ID, 
       ParentID  
FROM b1
WHERE b1.BOMLevel = 1
```

Comment: So far this is working incredibly well. At the very least I'm getting the same results as my standard query at a much quicker pace, especially on the server. I'll poke around with this but I think this a massive step in the right direction. Thanks.